# Pass values between two actions in a controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller

MVC Controller Action 1 : Displays values on a view page.

MVC Controller Action 2: Triggered by action link on the same view page - Takes the displayed values on the view page (values calculated in action 1) as parameters and runs its own logic.

Both are part of the same controller. Right now I am able to display values via action 1 successfully. Now the user clicks on the action link that takes execution to the action 2 .. But I am not able to successfully pass these values back to the controller action 2.

Controller Action 1:

```
 public ActionResult CalculationsONE()
{       
    var CalcModel = new CalcViewModel();

    int var1 = //Value calculated here
    int var2 = //Calculation

    CalcModel.Var1= var1;
    CalcModel.Var2= var2;

    return View(CalcModel);
}
```

View : The values from above are displayed on the view page.. like this.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<CalcModel>" %>

<table>
    <tr><td>First Value:</td><td><%=Model.Var1%></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Second Value:</td><td><%=Model.Var2%></td></tr>
</table>

<%=Html.ActionLink("StringTitle", "Action2", "Controller", new { var1 = Model.Var1,    

 var2=Model.Var2})%>
```

Now when the user clicks the action link, the values should be passed to Action 2 of controller. But thats not happening.. please help.

Action 2 code:

```
   public ActionResult Action2(int? var1, int? var2)
    {
       //Other logic/calculations.
    }
```

var1 and var2 are getting nulls from the view ..

Comment: Have you tried the low tech solution? `<a href="/Controller/Action2?var1=@Model.Var1&var2=@Model.Var2">StringTitle</a>`?

Comment: Have not. How do I write this in non-razor syntax? I will try this.

Comment: The snippet provided was an example. =D

Comment: Sure. I understand that. I tried using the same format .. but cant seem to get syntax right.. I am using aspx notation and not razor.

Comment: Oh, sorry, completely brain dead on my example there! It should be `<a href="/Controller/Action2?var1=<%= Model.Var1 %>&var2=<%= Model.Var2 %>">StringTitle</a>`

Comment: Works. thank you. You said low tech? is this not a best practice..and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a good or bad practice really; I simply find using the HTML Helpers for really simple links is overkill. In your situation, you were probably ending up attaching those values in the anonymous object as attributes on your link, instead of in the url.

Answer (score 0):

Your naming convention is wrong I believe, try

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<CalcView>" %>
```